# aws sam sync issue: Failed to sync infra. Code sync is paused until template/stack is fixed

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, synchronization, aws-sam

I'm using aws sam to build and deploy my typescript nodejs repo in aws. I need to use `sam sync` to sync my project because I'm exhausted in always using `sam build` and `sam deploy` in every small change. But when I use `sam sync --stack-name log-tracker-backend --watch` command I'm getting below error:

```
rm "...\log-tracker-backend\.aws-sam\auto-dependency-layer\RuntimeDependenciesLayer/nodejs/package.json"
Failed to sync infra. Code sync is paused until template/stack is fixed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '...\\log-tracker-backend\\.aws-sam\\auto-dependency-layer\\RuntimeDependenciesLayer\\nodejs\\node_modules\\log-tracker-backend'
```

However code in my files are:
template.yml:

```
# This is the SAM template that represents the architecture of your serverless application
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-template-basics.html

# The AWSTemplateFormatVersion identifies the capabilities of the template
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/format-version-structure.html
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  log-tracker-backend

# Transform section specifies one or more macros that AWS CloudFormation uses to process your template
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-section-structure.html
Transform:
  - AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Globals:
  Function:
    Layers:
      - !Ref RuntimeDependenciesLayer
    Environment:
      # # Environment variables used by every function
      Variables:
       SAMPLE_BUCKET: !Ref LogDataBucket
    Runtime: nodejs18.x
    MemorySize: 128
    Timeout: 100

# Resources declares the AWS resources that you want to include in the stack
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resources-section-structure.html
Resources:
  # Each Lambda function is defined by properties:
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction

  # This is a Lambda function config associated with the source code: in src/handlers/example.ts
  getLogsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: makefile
    Properties:
      Handler: dist/handlers/get-logs.getLogsHandler
      Policies:
        - S3ReadPolicy:
            BucketName: !Ref LogDataBucket
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /logs/{group}
            Method: GET

  postLogsFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: makefile
    Properties:
      Handler: dist/handlers/post-logs.postLogsHandler
      Policies:
        - S3WritePolicy:
            BucketName: !Ref LogDataBucket
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /logs
            Method: POST

  LogDataBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: s3-log-data-wealthos
      AccessControl: Private
          
  # Shared layer with Lambda runtime dependencies
  RuntimeDependenciesLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: makefile
    Properties:
      LayerName: "log-tracker-backend-dependencies"
      Description: Runtime dependencies for Lambdas
      ContentUri: ./
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - nodejs18.x
      RetentionPolicy: Retain

Outputs:
  WebEndpoint:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

samconfig.toml:

```
version = 0.1
[default.deploy.parameters]
stack_name = "log-tracker-backend"
resolve_s3 = true
s3_prefix = "log-tracker-backend"
region = "us-east-2"
confirm_changeset = true
capabilities = "CAPABILITY_IAM"
disable_rollback = true
image_repositories = []
```

Comment: did you `sam build`?

Comment: @petey yes, before the deploy